# C# Cannot access child public method from abstract parent class object

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class, class-relationship

I'm learning OOAD and trying to implement class relationship with inheritance but there is an issue here is the code

**Parent Class**

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    abstract class Classification
    {
        public abstract string type();
    }
}
```

**1st Child Class**

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class FullTime : Classification
    {
        bool inCampus;
        string roomDetail;
        float rent;

        public FullTime(string studentRoomDetail, float studentRent)
        {
            this.inCampus = true;
            this.roomDetail = studentRoomDetail;
            this.rent = studentRent;
        }

        public FullTime()
        {
            this.inCampus = false;
        }

        public string printAccommodationDescription()
        {
            if (!this.inCampus)
            {
                return "Not in campus";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Room: " + this.roomDetail + " Rent: " + this.rent.ToString();
            }
        }

        public override string type()
        {
            return "fulltime";
        }
    }
}
```

**2nd Child Class**

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class PartTime : Classification
    {
        bool onJob;
        string jobTitle;
        float salary;

        public PartTime(string studentJobTitle, float studentSalary)
        {
            this.onJob = true;
            this.jobTitle = studentJobTitle;
            this.salary = studentSalary;

        }

        public PartTime()
        {
            this.onJob = false;
        }

        public string printJobDescription()
        {
            if (!this.onJob)
            {
                return "Not on job";
            }
            else
            {
                return "JobTitle: " + this.jobTitle + " Salary: " + this.salary.ToString();
            }
        }

        public override string type()
        {
            return "parttime";
        }
    }
}
```

Now in **Program.cs** when I tried to access method `printJobDescription` from `PartTime` class

```
Classification classification = new PartTime("Software Engineer", 10000);
classification.printJobDescription();
```

it says

> Error CS1061  'Classification' does not contain a definition for 'printAccommodationDescription' and no extension method 'printAccommodationDescription' accepting a first argument of type 'Classification' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I solve this issue?

**UPDATE**

I need the ability to let object change its class at runtime, so I have to create the object of type `Classification` and use either method that is not implemented in other class

Comment: You are using the type Classification. This type has´t the printJobDescription() method. So you cant´t use it. To use this method it have to be the type PartTime.

Comment: but I also need the ability to let object change its class on runtime, so I have to create the object of type Classification and use either method that is not implemented on other class

Comment: I will add some code ... just a moment :-)

Comment: thankyou @Fruchtzwerg...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use the functions declared in the class you use.

```
abstract class Classification
{
  public abstract string type();
}

class PartTime : Classification
{
  public override string type() {...}
  public Job1() {...}
}

class FullTime : Classification
{
  public override string type() {...}
  public Job2() {...}
}
```

- A object of type Classification can only use the type()
- A object of the type PartTime can use type and Job1()
- A object of the type FullTime can use type and Job2()

If you have an object like this:

```
Classification classification = new PartTime();
```

and you don´t know which special type, you have to cast this object to use other methods:

```
if (classification is PartTime)
{
  ((PartTime)classification).Job1();
}
else if (classification is FullTime)
{
  ((FullTime)classification).Job2();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Of course type casting. yes it helps, Thankyou Sir :)

Answer (score 0):

When casting you're object into another object type, that called [Polymorphism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx). This translate that you can only use the methods and properties that exposed to the destination object type, which is `Classification` which doesn't know your method.

Simple example i made:

```
using System;

namespace Program
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Dog rex = new Dog();
            Animal rexAsAnimal = rex;

            // Can access 'MakeSound' due the fact it declared at Dog (Inherited by Animal)
            Console.WriteLine(rex.MakeSound()); // Output: Bark

            // Compilation error: rexAsAnimal is defined as 'Animal' which doesn't have the 'Bark' method.
            //Console.WriteLine(rexAsAnimal.Bark()); // Output when uncomment: Compilation error.

            // Explicitly telling the compiler to cast the object into "Dog"
            Console.WriteLine(((Dog)rexAsAnimal).Bark()); // Output: Bark
        }
    }

    public abstract class Animal
    {
        public abstract string MakeSound();
    }

    public class Dog : Animal
    {
        public override string MakeSound() { return Bark(); }
        public string Bark()
        {
            return "Bark";
        }
    }
}
```